# Dynamic fields on Jsp Page

Tags: java

I would like to develop an application which is capable of adding fields dynamically in page. For example,

Student module will have fields like name,email,mobile and dob etc. To create the student record user must fill all the fields. This is fine for customer 1. But for customer 2 want to have other fields like gender, father and mother which is not required for the customer 1.

They are two different customers, say customer 1 is managing schools and customer 2 is managing colleges, hence their business is different.

To address the customer 2 requirement, it would be ideal to provide ability to add fields dynamically on page as per the customers. May be through seed data for page fields that constructs the page dynamically.

**Precise Question :**

In Module, Ability to construct the page dynamically with the fields from database. Typically fields are name,email,mobile, dob,parent mobile and address.
Upon submission, respective values should be stored into the respective database columns.

Currently we are using spring, struts and hibernate technology for the application, I think to support this requirement existing frameworks may not work and need to develop framework or any other existing framework that supports this requirement ?

Could you please provide any suggestion or links to accomplish this task.

help is greatly appreciate.

Comment: Customer1 , Customer 2 are type or names of customers ?

Comment: They are two different customers and types also, Lets say customer 1 is managing schools and customer 2 is managing colleges, hence their business is different.

Comment: I can't see the problem. You know in the backend whether you're going to manage the first or the second customer type, so you can provide personalized views. If you are _forced_ to use the same view, then you should cover all the possibile cases by including in the model a form class able to comprehend all the attributes of both customers.

Comment: Hi MaVVamaldo - I mean customer should ability to add the fields dynamically which appear into the screen. Application should ability to display the fields from database and construct the jsp page and then display to User upon submit then values should be stored into database. If customer wants to add 2 more fields(addr, parent mobile) then simple seed data would enough without modifying the application. the newly added 2 fields is specific to the customer not for the other. Please let me know if required further description.

Comment: Hi  Aleksandr M/Thomas , I have updated the question for precise expectation. Can make it active as i want to know the other opinion on this.